# What is the correct ics file for editing only one occurrence from the series

Tags: icalendar

I have ICS file AS

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES: MEETING
UID:PPLSCH_574
DESCRIPTION:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
SUMMARY:
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:no-reply@mailid.com
ATTENDEE;CN="Anya Julian, Julian Smith";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:valid@mailid.com, valid@mailid.com
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20160729T080000Z;
DTSTART:20160727T073000Z
DTEND:20160727T080000Z
TEXT:
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

It creates recurring event on 27, 28 and 29 July 2016 from 4:30 AM to 5:00 AM.
My task is to update time of event on 28 July to 4:30 AM to 6:00 AM.
Requirement is, updating time should not break series.
Please help me to create proper ICS for this requirement.

I got EXDATE and EXRULE but, I am not getting how to use it according to my scenario.

My second ics file is

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES: MEETING
UID:PPLSCH_574
DESCRIPTION:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
SUMMARY:
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:no-reply@mailid.com
ATTENDEE;CN="Anya Julian, Julian Smith";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:valid@mailid.com, valid@mailid.com
RECURRENCE-ID:20160728T073000Z;
SEQUENCE:8
DTSTART:20160728T073000Z
DTEND:20160728T083000Z
TEXT:
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a new REQUEST with a RECURRENCE-ID corresponding to the original instance dtstart time for the 28th and a DTSTART with the new datetime.

```
...
BEGIN:VEVENT
RECURRENCE-ID: 20160728T073000Z
DTSTART: 20160728T073000Z
DTEND: 20160728T083000Z
SEQUENCE: 1
```

Have a look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-4.4.2

Comment: I have edited my question with second ICS file using your solution. It removes all other events from calendar and updated desired event with new time. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, your RECURRENCE-ID contains a semicolon at the end. It is also quite hard to give a meaningful response if you change the elements of your question.